# function not working onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Okay so in my chrome extension I made this button show up on http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?ForumID=35 and whenever I click the button nothing happens. I've tried everything and I still can't seem to figure out the problem. Something wrong with my $.post()? I don't even know... Why?

```js
// Main Variables
console.log("pls");
var title   = "==// POST FOR AN AUTO ACCEPT!!! \\\\==";
var body    = "...or counter.\n\nYOU SEND TO ME.";
var link    = "http://www.roblox.com/Forum/AddPost.aspx?ForumID=35";

// Main Function

function postThread() {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        $.post(link, {
            __EVENTTARGET: data.match(/id="__EVENTTARGET" value="(.*)"/)[1],
            __EVENTARGUMENT: data.match(/id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="(.*)"/)[1],
            __VIEWSTATE: data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+)"/)[1],
            __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: data.match(/id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="(.+)"/)[1],
            __EVENTVALIDATION: data.match(/id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+)"/)[1],
            ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$NewPostSubject: title,
            ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostBody: body,
            ctl00$cphRoblox$Createeditpost1$PostForm$PostButton: "Post",
            comments: "",
            rdoNotifications: ""
        }).always(function() {
           alert("Thread posted.");
        });
    });
}

// Button Setup

var mdiv = document.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_ThreadView1_ctl00_NewThreadLinkTop").parentNode;
var btn = document.createElement('a');
btn.innerHTML = "Ask for trades";
btn.setAttribute("class", "btn-control btn-control-medium verified-email-act");
btn.setAttribute("id", "ctl00_cphRoblox_ThreadView1_ctl00_NewThreadLinkTop");
btn.setAttribute("onclick", "postThread()");
mdiv.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: console.log inside of the function you're passing to $.get.

Answer (score 0):

The web page can't see functions of your content script for [security reasons](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). Use `addEventListener` on the element instead.

Comment: Ahhh, this is what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: To add to this, the [link to relevant documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

Comment: "Security reasons" are not the only reasons though. It also prevents code conflicts (i.e. 2 different jQuery versions).

Comment: Well, "security" is a broad term, making your code safe due to isolation is part of security. Moreover it's done exactly for "security reasons".